# Is it certain that "experimental physics has not already detected an unexpected spontaneous collapse"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse

The WikiPedia page for the [Ghirardi–Rimini–Weber theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghirardi%E2%80%93Rimini%E2%80%93Weber_theory) states that "experimental physics has not already detected an unexpected spontaneous collapse". Is this really true? What would be the interpretation if somebody measured e.g. a thousand polarizations that were supposed to be entangled, and one of them appeared not to be entangled? My guess is that it would be regarded as an error in the measurement, not a spontaneous collapse of the wave function.

Is the lack of detection because there are no spontaneous collapses, or because experimenters look for the rule rather than the exception?

Comment: Experimenters love finding the exceptions to the rule, but worry a lot about noise and other ways of being fooled.